# how to set header location in PHP?

Tags: php, html, header

i need to go to this location:

```
<a href="<?=$aGetDomainData['domain_url']?>/backend/signout.php?lang=<?=$sLang?>">
```

but i have to make it in a php code like this:

```
  header("location:../../backend");
```

it is for a function that after the account is deleted you go back to the login screen. 
i already tried to do it local like: ../../backend. but there its a big possibility that the path is gonna change later so to do it local is not really an option.

Comment: why not use absolute paths? o.O

Answer (score 1):

Simple use code like this:

```
header("location: $aGetDomainData['domain_url']/backend/signout.php?lang=$sLang");
```

---

Edit after comment:
Before you delete account save variable like `$a=$aGetDomainData['domain_url'];` and `$b=$sLang;` then `DELETE` and header like `header("location: $a/backend/signout.php?lang=$b");`

Comment: no i cant, because by then the account  is alreadt deleted so i dont have acces to that folder anymore

Comment: @emmea you are not making much sense here. You said yourself that you need to go to that location at the very beginning of your question. You did not mention anything about stuff getting deleted/removed in between anywhere. Please edit your question, so that it contains an _accurate_ description of the problem you need to solve.

Comment: @emmea, there is no difference between your `<a>` tag and provided `header()` location, so better explain if there is additional logic behind